# String or binary data would be truncated. but i can't save it other way

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I have this code where I'm trying to update the value of the column `consultas_marcadas` with a string, here is the function that does that (this function is in a class called "dataclass"):

```
public bool SetValorPaciente(String nome, String coluna, String valor)
{
    bool flag = false;

    string strCmd = "UPDATE Paciente SET @coluna = @valor WHERE nome = @nome; ";

    using (SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(conString))
    using (SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand(strCmd, objConn))
    {
        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@coluna", coluna);
        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valor", valor);
        objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", nome);

        objConn.Open();
        objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        flag = true;
        objConn.Close();
    }

    return flag;
}
```

And here is where it's getting the value of the condition (`nome`), column to update (`consultas_marcadas`) and the value to update (`consultas`) which are all strings by the way.

```
dataclass datac = new dataclass();
bool valor = datac.SetValorPaciente(nome, "Consultas_Marcadas", consulta);
```

when I try to run the code I keep getting this error:

> 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code.
>   String or binary data would be truncated.

which after digging around for answers seems to show up because my column (`consultas_marcadas` in this case) only accepts smaller strings than the one I'm giving, now that is a problem that I can't seem to get past:

- I have changed my column data type from `Varchar(Max)` to `NVarchar(Max)` and even to `TEXT` but that still didn't work;
- I have tried to change the string `consulta` and make it just the first word, and that didn't give me any errors but it also never updated the table which is weird.

So given that I'm asking for 2 things:

- Is it possible to stop getting this error?
- What is the best method for saving long strings? Maybe SQL is not the thing I should be looking for, maybe there's a way to save this text to a file and then save that file somewhere and read it later, what do real programmers who have to deal with long strings every day do?

Comment: You can not pass column name as sql parameter.

Comment: _I have changed my column data type from Varchar(Max) to NVarchar(Max) and even to TEXT but that still didn't work;_ - because you are using `AddWithValue` - this method trying to guess sql parameter attributes - for example for string "Consultas_Marcadas" it will create parameter of type Varchar with Size = 18.

Comment: Thank you Fabio for your answer you just solved my problem, also is there a way to pass a column name or do I need to make one of this functions for every column that I want to update?

Comment: Personally, I would suggest to have dedicated method for every column. Yes, it looks similar, but update logic for different columns will change in different rates and for different reasons, so I would like to keep such methods separated.

Comment: ok, thank you. That helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you want to solve the error without throwing the exception.

First, We need to create the following table in database if all the fields are string type.

[image]

Second, you can use the following code to update your database.

```
  public bool SetValorPaciente(String nome, String coluna, String valor)
        {
            bool flag = false;
            string strCmd = "UPDATE Paciente SET coluna = @coluna,valor=@valor WHERE nome = @nome; ";

            using (SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(conString))
            using (SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand(strCmd, objConn))
            {
                objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@coluna", coluna);
                objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@valor", valor);
                objCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", nome);

                objConn.Open();
                objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                flag = true;
                objConn.Close();
            }
            return flag;
        }
```

Note: I modified the code about `strCmd` sentence.

You can update the `coluna` and `valor` when you find the same value as nome.